# Listen smart contract event

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design

I use

```
parity --light
geth  --syncmode "light"
```

I would like to listen smart contract Event.  Do I need to download all blockchain on local PC or light mode will be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends your needs and the trust you have in third-party nodes. The light mode is enough if you just care about listening to the events.

You can use Infura's websocket instead of syncing in light mode or "full" mode.